# JQuery and css3 removing items and having other items animate to fill space

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a grid, and what I'm trying to do is when you click a button (orange in demo) some of the items animate out rotate and fade out, and while this is happening the other items animate to fill to space, literally moving on top of them while they're animating out.

I'd like to do this with out a plugin for the sake of learning, but I'm having a bit of a hard time with two things.  One the opacity change animation doesn't happen, I'm trying to do it with CSS3.  And the second thing is I'm not really sure how to go about having the remaining items animate to fill the grid gaps.

This is what I have set up right now, I was hoping some people can give me some thoughts on this, here is what I started with:  http://jsbin.com/uYayuXe/8/edit

Comment: The only solution I see here (without plugins) is by using position absolute values. Is that ok for this example? Otherwise you should consider finding a nice grid based JQuery Plugin.

Comment: so how would you set up a grid with the values being absolute?

Comment: Check this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/h9JyC/9/ Get the idea?